# Brushes in Win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to change the entire screen color to blue in **C++**.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>

void Color()
{
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

    COLORREF color = 0x000000FF;
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(color);
    SetDCBrushColor(hdc, color);
    PatBlt(hdc, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, PATCOPY);

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

My problem is that it's setting the color to **white instead of red**.
I searched a solution to my problem but got photoshop tutorials.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `GetDesktopWindow()` does not represent the screen. Use `GetDC(0)` instead to draw on the screen. Also, consider using the [`RGB()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rgb) macro instead of hard-coding `COLORREF` values. And what is the point of using `CreateSolidBrush()` if you are not going to use the `HBRUSH`? And you are leaking the `HBRUSH`. To use the `HBRUSH` properly, use [`SelectObject()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) instead of `SetDCBrushColor()`, and `DeleteObject()` when you are done using it.

Comment: Thank you it worked!
But i didn't had to use GetDC(0)

Comment: Just note that the [screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-virtual-screen) and the [desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/winenv-desktop) are two different things.

Comment: Neither DC belongs to you. Whatever you are doing is subject to get removed the next time the owner of the DC performs its rendering.

Comment: One method to draw over the screen in a way that's more sanitary is to have your own window that covers the entire screen and has a colour key for transparency. This way, you have your own DC to use. Naturally, there's no way to force your window to be the topmost window 100% of the time, but with the right intentions, that shouldn't be problematic. Drawing over the screen also isn't something that tends to work very well in a consumer-facing application unless that's its primary purpose.